# Извлечение данных из PHP файла и запись их в БД

Tags: php, json, база-данных, парсер

Всем доброго времени суток, у меня проблема.

Хочу спарсить один файл на сайте и извлечь из него данные. Файл PHP, но он похож больше на JSON, нужно сделать так: из этого файла вытаскивать некоторые данные о машине, и затем записывать их в любую БД. Вот ссылка на сам файл, парсил через Postman, POST-запросами.

Буду очень признателен за помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ссылку я не нашел. А что в вашем понимании PHP файл пхожий на JSON? Очень не хватает конкретики

Comment: Ой, забыл ссылку вставить, вот она, сайт немецкий, но разбираться не надо. Если просто ввести в адресную браузера, ничего не получится, нужно именно парсить, я делал через Постман, вообщем вот ссылка: https://www.autohaus-royal.de/data/filter.php нужно из этого файла вытеснуть характеристики разные машин, и их записать в БД. Спасибо!

Comment: Не «похож больше на JSON», это и есть JSON, который можно распарсить любым удобным json-парсером https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: а можете пожалуйста сказать, как потом данные засунуть в БД?

Answer (score 2):

Парсите файл любым удобным способом, можно с помощью библиотек или нативными средствами языка PHP. Например,

```
$content = file_get_contents(<тут ссылка на файл>);
$content = json_decode($content, true); // преобразование контента из JSON в ассоциативный массив
```

Далее, чтобы вставить в базу данных, используйте PDO (убедитесь, что ваш на вашем сервере установлен/включена поддержка PDO)

**1. Соединение с базой данных**

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo', 'root', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

**2. Добавляем данные в БД**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `имя_таблицы` (`поле1`, `поле2`) VALUES (:значение1, :значение2)";
$params = [
    ':значение1' => $contents['total'],
    ':значение2' => $contents['page_num'],
    ...
]2
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Думаю основная логика понятна, вложенный массив items[] вы распарсите как вам нужно и положите в базу данных куда вам нужно. Возможно понадобится цикл и т.д. Я описал вам алгоритм

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Артемий, человек старался, отметьте его ответ, как правильный - на спасибо далеко не уедешь